# How to dynamically divide html space evenly

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am working on a Angular application and css / html is killing me right now.
Here is a general Setup of my [application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF2Md.png). What I am trying to accomplish is to create the center component (Component 1 in the Sketch) with the button from Component 2.

So what my html would look like is:

```
<div>
      <div>
          <cluster-row> </cluster-row>
          <template #placeholder> </template>
      </div>
      <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-circle (click)="insertClusterRow()"> + </button>
      <div>
</div>
```

How would I accomplish to divide the center part of component1 without overflowing the max-height of the browser. 
So basicly button gets pressed template gets replaced with instantiated component1 from code and divides the center part in halve max to a quarter for each one.

Hope what I wrote makes sense and the sketch helps picturing the intended effect.

Kind regards,

Vitax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `d-flex`, `flex-column`, `w-100`, and `h-100` classes for the container. And for `the component-1` - component that takes all the available space in the container, use `flex-grow-1`. Keep in mind that you need to use `Boostrap-4.1` because `bootstrap-4.0` does not the have `flex-grow-1`. It only works if all the parents of the container including `html` and `body`have `100%` height.

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column w-100 h-100">
  <div class="">title</div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1">Component 1</div>
  <div class="">Component 2</div>
</div>
```

#### A working demo. Recommend you to run it in full screen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="h-100">
<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="h-100">
  <div class="container-fluid  h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-column w-100 p-0 ">
        <div class="bg-success p-3">title</div>
        <div class="flex-grow-1 bg-primary p-3">Component 1</div>
        <div class="bg-info p-3">Component 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If the container has too many parents, comment and I will show you how to do it with absolute positioning, or perhaps, you should try it yourself.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment.This works and I will figure things out from here. This was a big help and lead me into the right direction. I need to learn, to write clean css / html which is hard when it is not your job most to the time.